# Does MagSafe 2 T Connector get really hot when charging?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature, magsafe

I've a Macbook Pro Retina 15" Late 2013. My MagSafe 2 connector (T connector) gets really hot when charging.

Is it normal ??

Comment: Yeah, I think so, mine is hot too, sometimes.

Comment: What is really hot? How warm is the air temperature where you charge? Is the Mac off?

Comment: While mac working & charging (Orange light). Around 60C

Comment: It could be due to the applications that are running, consuming your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my case, my new MacBook Pro Retina 13" MagSafe connector gets insanely hot but once the charge level reaches above 50% or so, it starts to cool down and then stays lukewarm.

The best solution is to not let the Mac's battery discharge too much. It also doesn't make much of a difference to the heat level if your Mac is on or sleeping as the heat level in both cases are similarly high.

Comment: getting hot is normal. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It can normally become warm, especially if you are using a lot of processor power and have the computer plugged into the magsafe 2 power supply. In my case, a malfunction of either the battery  (on a late-2012 MacBook Pro 15 in. with Retina) or the Magsafe module in the computer was at fault. I replaced both eventually and went through two 85W OEM chargers. I was getting what must have been micro arcing at one of the hot leads in the magsafe plug gap that left one part of the contacts sooted and pitted away--like an EDM wire. Fortunately parts replacement, new battery and new magsafe module (and a new magsafe 2 power supply) has appeared to correct the problem.

I unplug the power supply if I think it is heating up, although it has not heated anywhere near as much as it did before the parts replacement.